# How to apply pitch bend to MIDI notes using jMusic Java Library

Tags: java, midi, pitch

I am using jMusic, a Java music library, to create an Ear Trainer application and I would like to play MIDI notes that are slightly detuned by intervals less than semitones. I think I can achieve this by applying a pitch bend to the notes, does anyone know how to do this?

It doesn't specifically have to be using jMusic, if you know any way I could apply pitch bend to MIDI notes in Java that would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: what about the library the guy is talking about http://stackoverflow.com/a/18955373/5185646?

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich thanks, I saw this post earlier, but it says that library is for C/C++ but my application is written in Java. Would I be able to still use it somehow?

Comment: Well, if you have some more time to investigate how to include C/C++ code - then it should work. At least in android gamedev they write all the code in java except the things like shaders. For this low level things they use C++ libraries

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich ah right I see, thanks!

Comment: If it appears to be helpful for you and work please do not forget to answer the question as it may be helpful for other guys)

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich will do :)